# Mysql Show On Unseen

Tags: mysql

I am working on a photo sharing application where users will be able to upload their own images and vote/comment on the images uploaded by others, in our app, we want to implement a feature which will only show them the rows they have never seen, means once they see an image, it will be removed from their feed. Our picture table is pretty simple

```
picture_id (int 255, PK) | picture_title (varchar 255)
```

the table which tracks the views is

```
view_id (255, PK) | picture_id (255) | user_id (255)
```

previously we have been using a simple NOT IN query to achieve this result

```
SELECT * FROM pictures where picture_id NOT IN (SELECT picture_id from views where user_id=255)
```

that was working fine but since our views table has gone past 20 Million rows, the query takes a long time in preparing state, I am looking for suggestions to rewrite this query or optimize it.

Thansk

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN

```
SELECT p.*
FROM pictures AS p
LEFT JOIN views AS v ON v.picture_id = p.picture_id AND v.user_id = 255
WHERE v.picture_id IS NULL
```

To make it efficient, make sure you have an index on `views.picture_id`.